# Is there anyway to verify validity of dlopen handle?

Tags: debugging, crash, dynamic-linking, gdb

In my case after my program cas dlclose program is crashing and I am not getting stack trace for dlclose or any function on upper frames. I know handle value of dlclose . Is there anyway to check if handle is corrupted after dlopen was done?